# Converting a matrix in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix

Let's say I've got a vector `a = [1 2 4]`. I want it converted into a vector which looks like this `b = [1 2 0 4]`, i.e. each number is placed into a correct position and since `3` is not included into the vector `a`, it is replaced by `0` in vector `b`. This can be done the following way:

```
a = [1 2 4]
b = zeros(1, size(a, 2));
b(1, a) = a;
```

I can't figure out a way to do the same for a matrix. For example,

```
c = [1 4 2 0; 3 1 0 0; 4 0 0 0; 1 3 4 0];
```

I need to convert into a matrix that looks like this:

```
d = [1 2 0 4; 1 0 3 0; 0 0 0 4; 1 0 3 4];
```

Any tips? How can this be done? How can I do this without using loops?

Comment: How did b = zeros(1, size(a, 2)); a(1, b) = b; achieve the change you asked?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Corrected above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a vectorized solution:

```
a = [1 4 2 0; 3 1 0 0; 4 0 0 0; 1 3 4 0];
b = zeros(size(a,1),max(a(:)));
[rowIdx,~] = find(a);
vals = a(a>0);
b( sub2ind(size(b),rowIdx,vals) ) = vals;
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this work? (Edited: fixed mistake.)

```
[m,n] = size(c)
d = zeros(m,n)
for i=1:m
    d(i,c(i,c(i,:)>0)) = c(i,c(i,:)>0)
end
```

Comment: Is there a way to this without using a loop? I'm working with very large data sets and loops tend to be very slow...

Comment: I think it is possible, but in this case, you are doing the same operation to each row, so it makes to loop over each row. Even for large matrices, I don't think a loop would make the procedure prohibitively slow.